# Inheritance + Foreign keys: missing ids

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a User, which has two Folders when it is created => `home_folder` and `trash_folder`. Each Folder has a creator (a User).

A Folder is an Entry through Joined Inheritance (it maybe does not matter in my issue).

When I am doing this:

```
new_user = User(name=name)

home_folder = Folder(name="Home",
                     folder_type=Folder.FolderType.home,
                     creator=new_user)

trash_folder = Folder(name="Trash",
                      folder_type=Folder.FolderType.trash,
                      creator=new_user)

session.add(home_folder)
session.add(trash_folder)
session.add(new_user)
session.commit()
```

I get my Folders correctly:

```
id  folder_type creator_id 
1   home        1
2   trash       1
```

But my user is not OK:

```
id  name    home_folder_id   trash_folder_id
1   Remi    <null>           <null>
```

Here is my gist code: https://gist.github.com/remimarenco/3a9919d58a1b5987cdced1fff62cc606

EDIT:

So, in fact my question was a bit like..."how do I add more magic to the magic?". It makes sense my home_folder and my trash_folder are not populated in my user, because there is no place where I set them specifically.

I guess I have to do these affectations after a `.flush()` or a `.commit()`, so the user is created and the folders are created too...

I would be happy to know if there is a way to link them on the fly, like saying that the folder we are creating is associated to the home_folder of the user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have created the folders and added the user with his/her name, but you have not associated the User to a Home/Trash folder. After you create all three objects, you still need to link them. For example:

```
session.add(home_folder)  # Home folder is created
session.add(trash_folder) # Trash folder is created
session.add(new_user)     # New User is Created

new_user.home_folder = home_folder  # Give the New User a Home Folder
new_user.trash_folder = trash_folder  # Give the New User a Trash Folder

session.commit()
```

Comment: Hi David!

Thanks for taking the time to help me out. I have tried to work around by adding the folders to the user but, I think, because I am using `backref` for the relationship I should not have to do these affections.

I tried, just in case, and I have this triggered:

`sqlalchemy.exc.CircularDependencyError: Circular dependency detected.`

What do you think is happening?